# With respect to life insurance, why is reversionary bonus called "reversionary"?

Tags: united-kingdom, life-insurance, terminology

I've googled reversionary bonus and can see that it's a an addition to insured benefits (often made annually).  But why is it called "reversionary"?  Is something reverting?  Who to?

Comment: what country are you located?

Comment: @Dheer I'm in the UK

Answer (score 1):

The term reversionary is more a legal term. See the meaning  [here](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/reversion)

For all practical purposes, its a additional amount declared and gets added to the survival value of a whole life policy.

Comment: Thanks.  From the link the legal term refers to rights reverting i.e. going back to some previous owner, after a period when they have belonged to someone else.  I just don't see what rights "revert" to anyone when an additional amount is added to a survival value.